# Image resizing in Scrollview

Tags: ios, xcode, imageview, scrollview

I have an `ImageView` in a `ScrollView` and resizing the `ScrollView` at some point. The problem is, that the `ImageView` is resizing to the same size as the `ScrollView`, but I want it to keep the original image size.

What I'm doing is this:

```
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height); // fullscreen scrollview
[scrollView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTopLeft]; //i want the content to be on the top left, thats correct right?
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(imageInScrollView.frame.size.width, imageInScrollView.frame.size.height)]; // now im setting the size of the content, which is like 200x200 but it shows in fullscreen
```

Please read the comments next to my code, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `autoresizingMask` for the `UIView`

> **autoresizingMask**
>   An integer bit mask that determines how the receiver resizes itself
>   when its superview’s bounds change.

You can do this like this:

```
[myImageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `contentSize` of `UIScrollView` does not affect drawing, it is only for scrolling purpose (ie defines a rect within which the user may scroll).

Please give more info about `imageInScrollView` and the `UIImageView` it is contained in. In particular check its `frame` property is correct to what you want and check its `autoresizingMask` : you probably want something like

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

Lastly, you should do :

```
 [scrollView setContentSize:imageView.frame.size];
```

as this is more simple

Comment: Hi, I checked the frame of both. the imageInScrollView(which is actually an ImageView) and the scrollview
 350.000000, 335.000000 // imageview -- 
 540.000000, 576.000000 // scrollview.. and its no use to put autoresizingnone

Comment: What is the `imageView.image.size` ?

Comment: sorry, the image.size is 350x335 and the frame of the imageView is instead: 540.000000, 516.857178

Comment: `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter` ?